# Access nested key value pairs

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a relatively simple nested JSON string for data below:

```
{  "d" : {
     "humidity": "39.21",
     "acc_y": "1.21",
     "ambient_temp": "24.21",
     "air_pressure": "1029.21",
     "object_temp": "23.21",
     "acc_z": "0.21",
     "acc_x": "3.21",
   } 
}
```

I have a c# windows service application which receives the JSON string and Deserialize string.

```
private static void client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages.MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
    {

        //Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(e.Message));
        string json = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(e.Message);

        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, object>>(json, new JsonConverter[] { new MyConverter() });

    }
```

I have a Myconvert Class which looks like this, which reads the JSON:

```
class MyConverter : CustomCreationConverter<IDictionary<string, object>>
{
    public override IDictionary<string, object> Create(Type objectType)
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        // in addition to handling IDictionary<string, object>
        // we want to handle the deserialization of dict value
        // which is of type object
        return objectType == typeof(object) || base.CanConvert(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject
            || reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);

        // if the next token is not an object
        // then fall back on standard deserializer (strings, numbers etc.)
        return serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

I can see the JSON data in my debug window in the obj object.

This may be a very straight forward question, how do i extract the JSON key value pair data (eg. humidity, ambient temp) to use in my program, as currently i can only see them in the debug window?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need a converter to deserialize this JSON.  A simple wrapper class will do it:

```
class Wrapper
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> d { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
Dictionary<string, object> obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper>(json).d;
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vnoQxi

Comment: Excellent.. thank you for you reply. nice simple solution!

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help.